# How to get the cookies value in the controller file from the browser or how to get varaible pass from one node file to other node file

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating an authentication system with the express now i have authenticated user and saved his email in cookies from the controller file as soon as user get authenticate now in another controller i need that cookie value but i am not able  to aceess it

Authenticate-controller.js

```
var Cryptr = require('cryptr');
cryptr = new Cryptr('myTotalySecretKey');
var express = require('express');
const ap = express();
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var connection = require('./../../config');
var localStorage = require('localStorage');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');


module.exports.authenticate = function (req, res) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;


    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            res.json({
                status: false,
                message: 'there are some error with query'
            });
        } else {

            if (results.length > 0) {
                decryptedString = cryptr.decrypt(results[0].password);
                if (password == decryptedString) {
                    jwt.sign({ email, password },
                        'secretkey',
                        { expiresIn: '10days' },
                        (err, token) => {
                            console.log('token:' + token);
                            module.exports = token;
                            console.log(token);
                            res.cookie('jwt', token);
                            res.cookie('Auth', 'true');
                            res.cookie('UName', email);
                            res.redirect('/../home.html');

                        }

                    );


                } else {
                    res.redirect('/Authentication/login.html');
                    console.log("Wrong Input");

                }

            }
            else {
                res.redirect('/Authentication/login.html');
            }
        }
    });
};
```

now in card-controller.js i want to acess that cookie so i am using this

```
let connection = require('/home/codemymobile/study/trello/config');
let Cryptr = require('cryptr');
let express = require("express");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var email = Cookies.get('UName');
module.exports.card = function (req, res) {

};
```

but my node shows error cookies not defined, i am preety new to node so any help would be appriciated
can we share the data from one controller file to the other file somehow?

Comment: This could help you https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html in order to read the cookies generated from your express app

Comment: @roag92 can you like tell me what is wrong in my code actually i have tried this way too it is also not working

Comment: Also this could help you https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/javascript/2019-03-29-node-jwt-authentication/

Comment: Take a look to my repository to get an idea => https://github.com/roag92/jwt-node

Answer (score 1):

Ok, regarding your second code snippet there are several things that I noticed.

You are using the cookie-parser package that you affected to the cookieParser variable but after you use `Cookies.get` but I don't see where `Cookies` is coming from? so maybe what you want to do is `cookieParser.get` but by checking the cookie-parser package I didn't see any `get` method so it's hard to help you here.

Other than that you should be able to see your cookies by using `req.cookies` inside your function.

I hope it will help you a bit...

Comment: cookies are stored in the browsers, so i am trying to retrive them

Answer (score 0):

Let me say you that if you want to store a JWT into a cookie and other extra information it could be stored or not depending on the size of your cookie.

For more information about max size for cookies check this: https://www.quora.com/What-Is-The-Maximum-Size-Of-Cookie-In-A-Web-Browser

On another hand, I saw a problem in your implementation that I recommend you the below:

If you are receiving a JWT, you would keep the nature of a JWT authenticator.

https://medium.com/@siddharthac6/json-web-token-jwt-the-right-way-of-implementing-with-node-js-65b8915d550e